# Read POST Parameters/Data in iOS Webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a PHP-File with POST Form-Data in Header
[PHP-File with Post Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw6g7.png)

I don't know how I can read that variables and save them into NSString's:

```
if([request.URL.absoluteString containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@config2.php", MAINLINK]])
{


            NSString * username = POST-DATA;
            NSString * password = POST-DATA;
            NSLog(username);
            NSLog(password);
```

Comment: Please explain your intention to post a question in stackoverflow.com, also your question seems to be pretty basic one and you can find the solution by searching properly.

Comment: `request.allHTTPHeaderFields`? What does it give?